# SQL Server stored procedure data read in web api controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem to read stored procedure data in a Web API controller. My stored procedure executes fine, but I can't read the data returned from it.

Here is my stored procedure execution code:

```
vm.SailorMovementByNavyNo = _sailorMovementService.getSailorMovementByNavyNo(navyNo);
```

`vm.SailorMovementByNavyNo` holds this data:

[image]

This stored procedure is executed successfully. But I can't read `vm.SailorMovementByNavyNo` data in my Web API controller. I want to read the `CurrentUnitId` column.

How to do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - as in **stored** inside your SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Comment: Can you provide a little more details related to how you are executing stored procedure

Comment: Using this code-  DataTable dataTable = dbObject.ExecWithSqlQuery(String.Format("exec [spName] {0}", param1));

Comment: Have you tried looking for the results in the datatable?

Comment: Yes, I fetch the datatable result and use any property of datatable result

Comment: You need to use anothher library or framework like sqlClient, Dapper, Entity frmework to fetch data from your stored procedure.  To do it by sqlClient you can give a focus on this post https://submitmysites.blogspot.com/2018/11/using-sqlclient-connect-to-sql-server.html you can also visit Mashesh Chand blog at -Sharp  Corner https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/executing-a-stored-procedure-programmatically/